# How to Unassociate Campaigns from Automations in Marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, marketingcloudapi

We have some automations which were tagged to a wrong campaigns. Now I dont find a way to un-tag/ unassociate those campaigns. Is there any way to do it via APIs or SSJS? I could not find anything on web.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @zuzannamj You can see the screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/XmD8GfD
There are campaigns tagged with different colors under each automations. I want to un-tagg them and could not find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

While I am familiar with SFMC campaigns, to be honest I am not sure which screen that screenshot in your comment is taken from and I couldn't find it. :D

Anyway: For the manual way of doing this, scroll towards the bottom.

via API:

You will need these permissions for your API installed package:
[image]

Then you can get the campaign IDs like so:

```
GET /hub/v1/campaigns
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/getCampaignCollection.html

```
{
    "count": 4,
    "page": 1,
    "pageSize": 50,
    "links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "/v1/campaigns"
        }
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "createdDate": "2021-09-09T12:05:04",
            "modifiedDate": "2021-09-09T12:05:04",
            "id": "YOURID",
            "name": "sample name",
            "description": "",
            "campaignCode": "99",
            "color": "bfe7ee",
            "favorite": false
        }
        /*, */
    ]
}
```

Identify your campaign from the items in response.
The campaign Id you need for the next steps is the value "id" in the response.

Next, retrieve all assets to the campaign using

```
GET {{restEndpoint}}hub/v1/campaigns/YOURID/assets
```

result:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "XXXXX",
            "campaignId": YOURID,
            "type": "AUTOMATION_DEFINITION",
            "objectID": "c7267945-2505-4e80-8de9-xxxxxxx",
            "createdDate": "2022-02-08T02:20:36"
        }
    ],
    "page": 1,
    "pageSize": 50
}
```

There is an API method to unassociate campaigns from assets, the asset being the "ID" ("XXXXX") from the latest response and the campaignId being "campaignId" ("YOURID") in the latest response.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/unassociateAssetToCampaign.html

```
DELETE {{restEndpoint}}/hub/v1/campaigns/YOURID/assets/XXXXX
```

===

You can orientate yourself / do the same manually via the UI through the top "tab" in the UI,

[image]

...unassociating is finding your relevant campaign's "storyboard" and hitting the button on the right:

[image]

Comment: ... and I am pretty unsure what the value of associating an automation to a campaign would be in the first place ... the only real application for this entire tool is that it helps grouping (in fact - is pretty much the only way to group) Email Sends in Datorama Reports for SFMC into a meaningful report.